# JQuery find index of focused input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I find index of a focused input field? For now I have this code:

```
var forma = $('form#mali_oglas'),
    pomoc = $('div[role=pomoc]'),    
    input = forma.find('input[type!=hidden], textarea');

    index = input.focus().index();
    console.log(index);
```

All that I get is number of input elements in the form (15 at the moment).

Comment: If you are looking for any input, either select, checkbox, or radios use the [':input' selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/). See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10881972/144665).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/QyUHv/

jQuery

```
var f = $('form');
f.click(function(){    
    $('#index').val($(':input:focus',f).index());    
});​
```

HTML

```
<form>    
<input value="hello"/><br/>
<textarea></textarea><br/>
<input/><br/>
<input/><br/>
<select><option>Option</option></select><br/>
<input/><br/>
</form><br/><br/>
Field Index with focus:
<input id="index"/>
```

​

Comment: @Sasha Use .find() or its shorthand as I have done above to find the input elements. :input is awesome but should be used to to narrow elements from a larger subset.

Answer (score 3):

use [`:focus selector`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)

```
index = input.index(input.filter(':focus'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:focus` selector:

```
index = forma.find(":focus").index();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`$.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) *gives* the selected element focus. Instead, you want to *select* the focused element. Luckily, jQuery's got you covered with [`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/).

```
var input = forma.find('input:focus, textarea:focus');
var index = input.index();
console.log(index);
```

Note: I removed the `[type!=hidden]` selector, as hidden input fields can never have focus.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the pseudo class to find the element that has focus.

```
input = forma.find('input:focus, textarea:focus');
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

NOT TESTED